# IDE 1.6.10 on LinuxMint 17.3 Cinnamon

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide

When compiling I get the error 
'as: unknown option »-mmcu=avr5« exit status 1'

I succeeded now using your piece of advise. Thank you so much.

Comment: Turn on verbose compilation and check the commands it is running.

Comment: I deleted the .arduino15 directory. Have I to delete also the directorie with all data of arduino?

Answer (score 1):

Delete or rename the old "Arduino15" directory located at /home/(username)/.arduino15    (a.k.a. ~/.arduino15) and re-install 1.6.10.